# How to list an entries selected nested categories?

Tags: entries, categories, children

I have a entry field populated by categories. The number of categories an entry can have is unlimited and the categories are set up as nested categories i.e.

- first level
- ---second level
- ------third level
- first level 2
- ---second level 2
- ------third level 2

I want to be able to list out any categories selected at the third level that the entry may have selected if a certain parent category is identified. So far I have the following code. This works but lists all child categories for the identified parent instead of just the selected ones.

What am I missing?

```
{% set cats = entry.categories %}
{% for cat in cats %}
    {% if cat.slug == 'secondlevel1' or cat.slug == 'secondlevel2' %}
        {% set catChildren = cats.descendantOf(cat.id).descendantDist('1') %}
        {% if catChildren | length %}
            {% for childCat in catChildren %}
                {% set image = childCat.buildingBlockIcon.first() %}
                    {% if image %}
                        <img alt="{{ childCat.title }}" src="{{ image.url }}" />
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

----- EDIT Solution -----

I worked this out

by changing one line of code line 4 above from

```
{% set catChildren = cat.level(2).children %}
```

to

```
{% set catChildren = cats.descendantOf(cat.id).descendantDist('1') %}
```

Now works a treat. Any better solutions feel free to post.

Comment: Give [this thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/display-entries-related-to-a-category-only-bottom-level) a peek. I think its very similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: @damon thanks for the link. But it's kind of the opposite to what I want to achieve. I'm looking at in reverse. I have the entry, from the entry I want to  obtain what third level categories have been assigned to it and then use these to link to a related entries page. At present I can only get it to list all third level categories and not just the ones that were selected for the specific entry. So for example if the third level has 4 items and the entry only has 2 selected it still outputs all 4 items instead of just the selected 2. So I need a way to identify which items were selected.

Comment: @damon I've managed to solve it by using the descendantOf instead of level. I've edited my post with the answers above. Thanks for the clues!

Comment: @Lettie would you mind adding the solution you found as an official answer instead of an edit to the original question?

Comment: @bradbell no problem

Answer (score 1):

The final solution I got to work:

```
{% set cats = entry.categories %}
{% for cat in cats %}
    {% if cat.slug == 'secondlevel1' or cat.slug == 'secondlevel2' %}
        {% set catChildren = cats.descendantOf(cat.id).descendantDist('1') %}
        {% if catChildren | length %}
            {% for childCat in catChildren %}
                {% set image = childCat.buildingBlockIcon.first() %}
                    {% if image %}
                        <img alt="{{ childCat.title }}" src="{{ image.url }}" />
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```